# How to store a BinData field using Mule MongoDB Connector?

Tags: mongodb, mule

Using the Mule MongoDB connector, how do you store a field as a BinData type?

```
    <mongo:insert-object-from-map collection="#[variable:collectionName]">
        <mongo:element-attributes>
            <mongo:element-attribute key="msg_id">BinData(3, '#[message:id]')</mongo:element-attribute>
            <mongo:element-attribute key="shortcode">#[map-payload:shortcode]</mongo:element-attribute>
            <mongo:element-attribute key="msg">#[map-payload:msg]</mongo:element-attribute>
        </mongo:element-attributes>
    </mongo:insert-object-from-map>
```

This example above that I've tried just stores the string "BinData(3, 'eea894d1-b0b5-11e1-91c7-a769a8d50370')"

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have actually given up on the Mule MongoDB Connector entirely because it was not reliable and failed under a heavy load. This article explained why it failed so miserably - http://www.thorntech.com/2012/07/mule-mongo-connector-fails-under-heavy-load/

It was very easy to write my own Mule component that used the standard java driver. It performed significantly better and I had no problem saving any data type I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use Groovy to create the object

```
<mongo:element-attribute key="msg_id">#[groovy:new BinData(3, payload.getUniqueId())]</mongo:element-attribute>
```

That probably won't work though as the MongoDB Driver won't be able to [convert the object](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Java+Types),  but could use Groovy to instead create a [BasicDBObject to create the data that you store](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Java+Tutorial#JavaTutorial-InsertingaDocument).